# Chaining multiple .then, some functions without asynchronous code. Best practise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have one function that runs asynchronously, such as querying records from a database. The remaining code depends on the result, but runs synchronously. I am struggling to understand a good way to deal with this and would like to know the best practise?

Imagine the following code:

```
var usersDataPromise = getUsersDataFromDB();
var usersAgeArray = usersDataPromise.then(extractAges);
var averageAge = calculateAverageAge(usersAgeArray);
```

here, getUsersDataFromDB() runs synchronously and returns a promise. When the promise resolves, it runs extractAges(), a function that simply takes some of that data and returns an array. This function is sync. I want to pass that on to calculateAverageAge(), but this is where it breaks: calculateAverageAge does not wait for getUsersFromDB() to finish, and simply starts as soon as it can (usersAgeArray will be undefined).

What I tried:

I can make extractAges() return a promise instead of an array, and make calculateAverageAge wait with .then, by doing:

```
var usersDataPromise = getUsersDataFromDB();
var usersAgeArrayPromise = usersDataPromise.then(extractAges);
var averageAge = usersAgeArrayPromise.then(calculateAverageAge);
```

However, it feels as if I made the code needlessly complicated: I made extractAges() return a promise even though it runs asynchronously, not synchronously.

I realize I could have called calculateAverageAge() at the end of the extractAges function, but I'm trying to learn how to keep the code clean, and this feels as if I'm introducing side effects to a function that should only be extracting an array. Now the function description seems not fully accurate: it extracts an array but also calls on the next function.

I hope I've made this clear, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. What is the best way to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: Why is building an array from data asynch? Does it go back to server to do it?

Comment: Sorry, corrected - building an array is done synchronously. Edit - I realize I may have misunderstood the concepts. As all functions have to wait for one another to finish, they are therefore all async?

Comment: "*getUsersDataFromDB() runs synchronously and returns a promise.*" - sounds wrong in my ears. Why would you do that?

Comment: My bad Bergi I corrected it after AtheistP3ace's comment.  getUsersDataFromDB() runs async, as I understand it: the remaining code continues executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can make `extractAges()` return a promise instead of an array

There's no reason to do that. Only because you are using a function in a `then` callback, it doesn't need to return promises.

> and make `calculateAverageAge` wait with `.then`

Yes, you *need* to use `then` anyway, because the array is produced asynchronously and `usersDataPromise.then(extractAges)` always returns a promise. There's no alternative.

```
var averageAgePromise = getUsersDataFromDB().then(extractAges).then(calculateAverageAge);
```

Comment: So when I call a function in a .then, it will always return another promise? What happens if I make the extractAges function return an array? Will it be passed as an argument in the next .then function call?

(I think I finally understood the .then description [1], thanks!)

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Yes, `.then(…)` always returns a new promise for the result of the callback (that array in your case).

Comment: I have one final question I can't get working: If I'm chaining 3  functions, (like in your code example), how do I incorporate the catch?

Comment: You can chain `.catch(…)` on every promise (and it returns another promise as well), usually it's done in the end.